# Isotope images overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I am having an issue with Isotope. I am using it for a filterable gallery, but sometimes (not all the time), some of the images overlap.

http://www.rivka-photography.com/work/

It does not happen every time, you may have to refresh the page to see the problem. And for now I only witnessed it in Safari (latest version) on Mac. I am using imagesLoaded but it is not enough or so it seems. I tried both progressive layout and waiting for all images to be loaded. This is my current JS code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $grid = $('.gallery-isotope').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });

    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
      $grid.isotope('layout');
    });
});
```

BTW this is a Wordpress site. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried their suggested alternate setup (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded):

```
var $grid = $('.gallery-isotope').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // init Isotope after all images have loaded
  $grid.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
      layoutMode: 'masonry'
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried it. Works fine most of the time but sometimes images overlap. Very irritating.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured it out. I am pretty sure the problem came from Wordpress new responsive image size feature (introduced in 4.4). I altered the gallery code to gain control over what image size was being output and now it works.

Comment: super nice you figured it out, and I think you're right as to what the problem is... But would you be so kind to share with the world exactly HOW you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `setTimeout()`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $grid = $('.gallery-isotope').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });

    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $grid.isotope('layout');
      },200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried your solution but it does not solve the problem. Usually the layout is fine but sometimes images still overlap.